# Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved Error

Tags: errors

What is the problem with that code?

```
Öncelikli olarak \textbf{#include <mpi.h>} header'ını programımıza ekliyoruz. 
Ardından MPI programımızı başlatacak olan \textbf{MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);} 
fonksiyonumuzu yazıyoruz. Bu iki satır her MPI programında bulunmaktadır.
```

Error

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \re
served@a.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.512 Öncelikli olarak \textbf{#include <mpi.h>}
                                              header'ını programımız..
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `#` is a special character in LaTeX; to obtain a printed `#` you should input it as `\#`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Now it says
    Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text> 
                    $
    l.512 ...cak olan \textbf{MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);}

Comment: @TahsinGokalp: `&` is also special. Print it in the same way: `\&`.

Comment: Same for `\_ `. However, you should set code seuquences with `\verb|#include <mpi.h>|`

Comment: @TahsinGokalp if you want to typeset source code I would recommend to use the [minted package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf). It saves you the trouble to escape special characters and automatically highlights the code appropriately. For example with `\newmintinline{c}{}` (p. 30, for the options you can pass as second argument see p. 15) in the preamble you can use `\cinline|#include <mpi.h>|` in your document.